# Debian: Which installed packages came out of security/stable-updates/backports repo?

Tags: linux, debian

Is there something like dpkg -l which also shows where the package came from? Or otherwise: something like 'show all packages that were installed from the backports repo?

Also, the same question for main/contrib/non-free. Is this possible?